# SwiftUI: Cannot convert value of type 'Bool' to expected argument type 'Binding<Bool>'

Tags: swiftui

Creating a text-based game for SwiftUI

Wondering why can't I access isSelected in character ForEach loop? It gives the error:

> Cannot convert value of type 'Bool' to expected argument type 'Binding<Bool>'

on the line `Toggle(isOn: character.isSelected){`

Variable object declaration:
`@Binding var characters: [Character]`

Code here:

```
VStack {
    ForEach(characters) { character in               
        HStack{
            VStack(alignment:.leading) {
                Text("\(character.name)")
                    .fontWeight(.bold)

                Text("\(character.description)")
                .lineLimit(10)
                    
            }
            Spacer()
            Toggle(isOn: character.isSelected){
                Text("a")
            }.labelsHidden()
```

Answer (score 28):

In my case, I was in need to pass "true", not a var...

The solution was easy peasy:

```
.constant(true)
```

Comment: For me too, I needed this for `PreviewProvider` struct.

Answer (score 18):

I was getting the same error but in my case the **binding itself** was a `Bool`.

Fixed by adding `.wrappedValue`:

```
nameOfBinding.wrappedValue
```

Answer (score 13):

You just need to add a $:

```
Toggle(isOn: $character.isSelected){
```

Comment: Then your „@Binding var“ is at the wrong position or you mistyped the variable name.

Comment: You can't use this in a ForEach loop.

Answer (score 6):

A `character` itself is not bound, it is just a value, it needs to transfer binding from `characters` via subscript, so here is a solution (`.enumerated` is used to get access to index and value)

```
ForEach(Array(characters.enumerated()), id: \.element) { i, character in

    HStack{

        VStack(alignment:.leading) {
            Text("\(character.name)")
                .fontWeight(.bold)

            Text("\(character.description)")
            .lineLimit(10)

        }

        Spacer()

        Toggle(isOn: self.$characters[i].isSelected){ // << here !!
            Text("a")
        }.labelsHidden()
```

Comment: Thank you Asperi, I think this should be the accepted answer. ( When Foreach and Binding combined together. )