# Core Data + SwiftUI: Cannot convert value of type 'Bool' to expected argument type 'Binding<Bool>'

Tags: swift, list, toggle

I need to have some list with toggles. Data for list I’ve got from Core Data entity.

It’s my code

```
// get array products from Core Data
@FetchRequest(fetchRequest: Products.getAllProducts()) var myProducts: FetchedResults<Products>

// here I try to show List
List(myProducts.indices) { index in
    Toggle(isOn: self.myProducts[index].productStatus) {
        Text(self.myProducts[index].productName)
        }
}
```

Attribute isOn give me error: Cannot convert value of type 'Bool' to expected argument type 'Binding'

What need do?

Comment: Looks like a duplicate of [SwiftUI: Cannot convert value of type 'Bool' to expected argument type 'Binding<Bool>'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61853323/swiftui-cannot-convert-value-of-type-bool-to-expected-argument-type-binding) to me.

Comment: I saw but this decision didn’t help me. I think the problem is with the data format from Core Data. But I do not understand what the problem is?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 0):

I found solution for my case

```
ForEach(myProducts.indices){ index in
    Toggle(isOn:
        Binding<Bool>
         (get: {return self.myProducts[index].productStatus},
          set: { p in self.myProducts[index].productStatus = p}
         )) {
              Text(self.myProducts[index].productName)
         }
         .onTapGesture {
              self.myProducts[index].productStatus.toggle()
              do{
                  try self.managedObjectContext.save()
              }catch{
                  print(error)
              }
        }
 }
```

Only I don't understand about one line of code: 
set: { p in self.myProducts[index].productStatus = p}

Could somebody explain me?