# SwiftUI ToDoList with checkboxes?

Tags: swift

I want to write a ToDoList in swiftUI with core data. Everything works so far but I want to have a checkbox next to each item it Signify whether it is completed or not.

I have added a property isChecked:boolean in core data but I don't know how to properly read it from the database. How to use a Toggle() in my case?

```
struct ContentView: View {
    
    @Environment(\.managedObjectContext) var context
    
    @FetchRequest(fetchRequest: ToDoListItem.getAllToDoListItems())
    var items: FetchedResults<ToDoListItem>
    
    @State var text: String = ""
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            List {
                Section (header: Text("NewItem")){
                    HStack {
                        
                        
                        
                        TextField("Enter new Item.",text: $text)
                        
                        Button(action: {
                            if !text.isEmpty{
                                
                                let newItem = ToDoListItem(context: context)
                                newItem.name = text
                                newItem.createdAt = Date()
                                // current date as created
                                newItem.isChecked = false
                                
                                
                                do {
                                    try context.save()
                                } catch  {
                                    print(error)
                                }
                                
                                // to clear the textField from the previous entry
                                text = ""
                                
                                
                            }
                        }, label: {
                            Text("Save")
                        })
                    }// end of vstack
                }
                
                Section {
                    ForEach(items){ toDoListItem in
                        VStack(alignment: .leading){
                            
                            // to have a checkbox
                                            Button {
                                                toDoListItem.isChecked.toggle()
                                            } label: {
                                                Label(toDoListItem.name!, systemImage: toDoListItem.isChecked ? "checkbox.square" : "square")
                                            }
                            
                            
                            
                                            
                                            
                            if let name = toDoListItem.name {
                               // Toggle(isOn: toDoListItem.isChecked)
                                
                                Text(name)
                                    .font(.headline)
                            }
                                
                            
                            
                            //Text(toDoListItem.name!)
                                //.font(.headline)
                            
                            if let createdAt = toDoListItem.createdAt {
                                //Text("\(toDoListItem.createdAt!)")
                                Text("\(createdAt)")
                            }
                            
                        }
                        
                    }.onDelete(perform: { indexSet in
                        guard let index = indexSet.first else {
                            return
                        }
                        let itemToDelete = items[index]
                        context.delete(itemToDelete)
                         
                            
                        do {
                            try context.save()
                        }
                        catch {
                            print(error)
                        }
                    })
                }
            }
            .navigationTitle("To Do List")
        }
    }
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}
```

ToDoListItem.swift

```
class ToDoListItem: NSManagedObject,Identifiable {
    @NSManaged var name:String?
    @NSManaged var createdAt:Date?
    @NSManaged var isChecked:Bool
    // mapped to the entry properties in database
}


extension ToDoListItem {
    static func getAllToDoListItems() -> NSFetchRequest<ToDoListItem>{
        let request:NSFetchRequest<ToDoListItem> = ToDoListItem.fetchRequest() as!
        NSFetchRequest<ToDoListItem>
        // cast as todolist item
        let sort = NSSortDescriptor(key: "createdAt", ascending: true)
        // above order of sorting
        request.sortDescriptors = [sort]
        
        return request
    }
}
```

Should isChecked be an optional as well?

Comment: I have added Toggles, but still don't know how to set them individually. I have found an example to use set and get but can't modify it to work with my case:

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62403045/core-data-swiftui-cannot-convert-value-of-type-bool-to-expected-argument-ty